# Populate print template title text from a dojo textbox

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, printing, dojo

I have a print widget that starts up great. It's based on the typical ArcGIS print widget sample.

However, I want to tweak this a bit. There is a "titleText" property in the layout options that I want to set from a text box that the user types a title into.

So, based on the dojo textbox value, I assign that to the titleText property.

A lot of the code I find is in AMD so it's really tough to decipher (as I am still starting out in JSAPI).

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: can you post a fiddle or attachment of what you have so far?

Comment: I think I got it, John. Although, I used a different approach. What I did was call the print widgets destroy method on the printComplete event. Also, the widget is only initialized when a "Submit" button is clicked. That onClick event gets the value from the text box and assigns it to the titleText property of the print widget and then calls the print.startup() method. This brings up another button underneath the Submit button called "Print". This is the button created by the widget itself. Upon pressing that, the widget runs and spits out a link to the user.

Comment: very cool Ruchira!